# Mongoose-auth and connect-assetmanager not playing nice together

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using connect-assetmanager to consolidate js and css files, and mongoose-auth to authenticate users. Both features work independently, but don't seem to work together.

In this order, mongoose-auth works, but my minified js & css routes are broken:

```
app.use(
    mongooseAuth.middleware()
  , assetManager(assetManagerGroups)
);
```

In this order, the minified routes work, but req.user is not set by mongoose-auth:

```
app.use(
    assetManager(assetManagerGroups)
  , mongooseAuth.middleware()
);
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more code. I've definitely isolated it to these two lines, though, and check that I'm not using a wildcard route with assetmanager or anything. Thanks!

Comment: Connect-asssetmanager should only be consuming requests that match it's routes. Requests matching that route should never see latter middleware, those requests end with connect-assetmanager. Requests not matching any of the routes should hit mongooseAuth. Is this not what you're seeing?

Comment: I'm thinking this is actually an issue with the use() function, or my mis-understanding of it. Separating these into two app.use statements clears it up.

Comment: It's unclear if you need req.user populated when using the connect-assetmanager. If you're assetmanager routes break when mongoose is in front, it's a problem with mongooseAuth.

This really hints at the author of the module doing something that causes issues with routing (like never calling next()).

From the mongoose-auth docs: "// IMPORTANT!!!!!!! Do not add app.router, to your middleware chain explicitly, or you will run  into problems accessing `req.user` i.e., do not use app.use(app.router). Let express do this for you automatically for you upon your first app.get or app.post."